# What is this component ? Negative tiny LCD glass?

Tags: identification, components, lcd, optoelectronics

I disassembled a [ceiling projector clock](https://www.oregonscientificstore.com/p-9-oregon-scientific-rm313pna-blue-projection-atomic-alarm-clock-with-indoor-temperature.aspx) to find out how it achieves its projection. I found a very small screen (or glass, see image) backlit by an LED.

[image: Tiny negative LCD glass]

To build some projecting stuff, I would like to buy some similar components, but I cannot find any.

To me, this is a "tiny negative LCD glass" but everything that I found is either too big, or not negative, or with prebuilt backlight (what I call a screen, instead of a glass, but maybe it is not the right vocabulary):

- https://www.crystalfontz.com/product/cfao4265attl-42x65-graphic-lcd
- https://www.buydisplay.com/blue-serial-spi-small-0-96-inch-128x64-graphic-cog-lcd-display-module

What is the actual name/search keywordfor this component?

Comment: You can turn any LCD into a "negative LCD" by flipping one of the polarizers.

Comment: Try searching for "transmissive lcd micro display".

Comment: @Janka Thank for the advice. Do you have any "good" tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: Rotate the polarizer 90 degrees. That's all. However as the LCD isn't square, in reality you need to find a sheet of polarizer and cut a new one from it.